# Why is it unusual to add a date to scientific papers?

Tags: publications, citations, abstract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the date left out of some academic papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3424/why-is-the-date-left-out-of-some-academic-papers)

A scientific paper usually begins with a title, a list of authors with contact information and affiliation, and an abstract. There is usually no date to indicate when the paper was written or first published.

Yet, the first questions that comes to my mind when reading a new paper is often: When was it written? How current is this research? Can I expect that science has moved on since this was written?

However, when I suggested adding a date to the header of one of my own papers, my advisors reacted, surprisingly for me, as if this was a quite outlandish idea. The reason given was that it is "unusual". Is there any rationale behind this?

Comment: Hi clstaudt! I believe this question is a duplicate of that one: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3424/102. I'm closing it for now, please free to edit it if you feel it necessary.